# Find second order asymptotic approximations of solutions of non-linear equations

Tags: asymptotics

To compute asymptotic approximations of solutions $u(x,y),v(x,y)$ of the system of equations \begin{cases}
u^a+v^b+x+y= 4\\ u+v+x+y= 4
\end{cases}
near $(u,v)=(1,1),(x,y)=(1,1)$.

I replace $u^a$ by $1+a(u-1)$, similarly for $v^b$, I get a linear equation
\begin{cases}
1+a(u-1)+1+b(v-1)+x+y=4\\
u+v+x+y=4
\end{cases}
Solving this, I get the first order asymptotic
$$u_1=1+\frac{(x-1) (b-1)}{a-b}+\frac{(y-1) (b-1)}{a-b}\\
v_1=1+\frac{(x-1)(1-a)}{a-b}+\frac{(y-1) (1-a)}{a-b}$$
How to find the second order asymptotic?

Mathematica ([code](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/qBxGjxYQjy/)) gives the result
$$u_2=u_1-\frac{(a-1) (b-1) (a (2 b-1)-b) (x+y-2)^2}{2 (a-b)^3}\\
v_2=v_1+\frac{(a-1) (b-1) (a (2
   b-1)-b) (x+y-2)^2}{2 (a-b)^3}
$$

---

To compute asymptotic approximations of solutions $u(x,y),v(x,y)$ of the system of equations \begin{cases}
u^a+v+x^c+y= 4\\ u+v+x+y= 4
\end{cases}
near $(u,v)=(1,1),(x,y)=(1,1)$.

I replace $u^a$ by $1+a(u-1)$, similarly for $x^c$, I get a linear equation
\begin{cases}
1+a(u-1)+b+1+c(x-1)+y=4\\
u+v+x+y=4
\end{cases}
Solving this, I get the first order asymptotic
$$u_1=1+\frac{(1-c) (x-1)}{a-1}\\
v_1=2-y+\frac{(x-1) (c-a)}{a-1}$$
How to find the second order asymptotic?

Mathematica ([code](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/f37W2B4Nfm/)) gives the result
$$u_2=u_1-\frac{(c-1) (x-1)^2 (a (2 c-1)-c)}{2 (a-1)^2}\\
v_2=v_1+\frac{(c-1) (x-1)^2 (a (2
   c-1)-c)}{2 (a-1)^2}
$$